# Tracing the exact location of the longpressgesture with CGPoint

Tags: iphone, ios6, cgpoint

By using CGPoint location it is always saving the last image in uiscrollview. When i m tapping on other image to save. What can i do to save the exact image one i tapped.

```
UIScrollView *imageScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
imageScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

NSInteger numberOfViews = 61;

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++) {

    CGFloat xOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.width;

 NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d.png", i];

    _image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];

    _imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:_image];

    _imageView.frame = CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

 UILongPressGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                                       initWithTarget:self
                                                       action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];

    imageScrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [imageScrollView addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
    gestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
    [gestureRecognizer release];

    [imageScrollView addSubview:_imageView];
imageScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * numberOfViews, self.view.frame.size.height);

    - (void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer{
if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Save Photo", nil];
    actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent;
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
    [actionSheet release];

     }}

 -(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

switch (buttonIndex) {
    case 0:
        [self savePhoto];

       break;

    default:
        break;

}

   -(void)savePhoto{

CGPoint location = [gesture locationInView:_imageView];

if  (CGRectContainsPoint(_imageView.bounds, location)){

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(_image, self, @selector(image: didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
   }}}
```

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point will always appear within the bounds of the `UIScrollView` in which the `LongPressGestureRecognizer` is triggered. You should check your scroll view's `contentOffset`  (use `contentOffset.x` for horizontal layouts and `contentOffset.y` for vertical layouts) to detect which image you should save.

Additionally you could convert the touch point to the `UIImageView` instance's local coordinate system and see if the the point lies within the image view's `bounds` rect.

**UPDATE**

For example you could use something like this to detect if the point is within the image view's bounds (note: I have *not* tested this and this is assuming there is more than one image view added to the scroll view):

```
if (CGRectContainsPoint(_imageView.bounds, [self.view convertPoint:location toView:_imageView]))
{
    // do something
}
```

You should also consider detecting which image should be saved before and storing a reference to that image before displaying the `UIActionSheet` to the user as it may decrease the number of potential issues you might encounter and will be easier to read later, but this is my subjective opinion.

Comment: how can i put that in code when images are placed in a single row in my UIScrolView

Comment: No still having the same problem saving the last image in scrollview

Comment: Are you changing which image your `_image` ivar is referencing when the user scrolls through the images? If there is no other piece of code touching the reference then it will always be the last thing stored in it which, from your code sample above, looks to be the `for` loop that initializes the view hierarchy. Likewise, you also need to make sure the `_imageView` ivar is being updated when the user scrolls through the content.

Comment: what if i can tag them with [imageView setTag:i]; and retrieve them later with [scrollView viewWithTag:index+1]; that makes sense

Comment: Have your `UIViewController` adopt the [`UIScrollViewDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIScrollViewDelegate) protocol in the header (.h), set your view controller as the scroll view's delegate, then implement the `– scrollViewDidScroll:` method in the implementation (.m). Inside the `scrollViewDidScroll:` method, check the scroll view's `contentOffset` property and see how many "pages" the user has scrolled to detect which image is currently being shown.